# Binding DataFrames

Tags: r, dataframe, bind

I have several dataframes that have two columns, Year (which is present on all dataframes and have the same values) and each dataframe has a unique column with different data and column name.
I have 8 dataframes so I would like my new combined dataframe to have 9 columns, being the first one the column Year.

I've tried using rbind to combine the dataframes but I got an error saying:

```
rbind(df_GazaSampleSize, MeanSchoolingGaza, MeanAgeGaza, MeanLabourGaza, MeanWageEarnerGaza, MeanDaysWorkedGaza, MeanMarriedGaza, WorkInIsraelForGaza)

Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names
```

All of my dataframes have exactly two columns and 11 rows (without taking into consideration the column name). This is an example of one dataframe named MeanAgeGaza:

```
   year      age
1    81 33.04291
2    82 32.62763
3    83 32.65788
4    84 32.86730
5    85 32.67479
6    86 32.38068
7    87 32.72235
8    88 32.93970
9    89 33.27995
10   90 33.20490
11   91 33.24092
```

I would like for the columns to be arranged like:

Year, df_GazaSampleSize, MeanSchoolingGaza, MeanAgeGaza, MeanLabourGaza, MeanWageEarnerGaza, MeanDaysWorkedGaza, MeanMarriedGaza, WorkInIsraelForGaza
that's why I tried doing the rbind.

Is there any way to do this ? Any help is appreciated

Comment: The base R merge() function would be appropriate. rbind() is for concatenating (think of it as stacking on top of each other) dataframes that have the same columns.

Comment: Perhaps this is useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34393416/11832955